# Selección con CSS, usando entornos, o con find

Tags: javascript, jquery

Para seleccionar los descendientes (inmediatos o no) de un elemento en jQuery podría utilizar alguno de estos métodos:

- Selección con CSS:

  ```
  $("#padre .descendientes")
  ```
- Selección usando un entorno (suponemos que `$padre` es `$("#padre")`):

  ```
  $(".descendientes", $padre)
  ```
- Selección usando `find` (suponemos que `$padre` es `$("#padre")`):

  ```
  $padre.find(".descendientes")
  ```

Con los tres parece que obtengo los mismos resultados, ¿existe alguna diferencia entre ellos?¿es alguno de ellos más rápido o eficiente?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He hecho un test con [Benchmark](https://benchmarkjs.com/) y uno simple.

Y al parecer `$padre.find(".descendientes");`
es el más rapido.

---

[Ver el test con Benchmark](https://jsfiddle.net/2ofqx4j2/)

Resultado con Benchmark:

```
Test 1: $("#padre .descendientes")     x 469,189 ops/sec ±7.24% (80 runs sampled)
Test 2: $(".descendientes", $padre)    x 690,551 ops/sec ±0.73% (95 runs sampled)                           
Test 3: $padre.find(".descendientes")  x 743,511 ops/sec ±0.89% (91 runs sampled)

// El más rapido: Test 3
```

---

[Ver el test simple](https://jsfiddle.net/hca3ee9d/1/) (Ver los resultados en consola)

Resultado test simple:

```
Test 1: $("#padre .descendientes")    3361.640ms
Test 2: $(".descendientes", $padre)   2418.249ms
Test 3: $padre.find(".descendientes") 2287.109ms

// El más rapido: Test 3
```

Answer (score 2):

**$("#padre .descendientes")** Analizan el selector luego llaman a :
 `$('#padre ').children().filter('.descendientes')` y `$('#padre').filter('.descendientes')` respectivamente.

**$(".descendientes", $padre)** es idéntico a `$padre.find(".descendientes")`

**$padre.find(".descendientes")**  siempre será el más rápido

Prueba de ello [Test Selectors](https://jsperf.com/jquery-selectors-context/2)
Test Adicional [children-vs-find](https://jsperf.com/jquery-children-vs-find/100)

> En realidad, no tiene que preocuparse de lo que es más rápido (a menos que usted está haciendo una manipulación muy grandes del dom) ... `jQuery` fue construido para ser impresionante rápido.

Referencia https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177763/what-is-the-fastest-method-for-selecting-descendant-elements-in-jquery

Comment: Si el segundo y el tercero son idénticos, ¿por qué uno es siempre más rápido que el otro?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro según la documentación de jQuery, al utilizar el contexto, este es convertido a `.find()`, por lo cual el segundo método tomaría al menos un "paso" adicional comparado con el tercero. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context